# Unable to execute cr9idata.pl

Tags: oracle, perl

Oracle Database Home patches installed successfully

Executing cr9idata.pl

Executing: perl /u01/db/VIS/12.1.0/nls/data/old/cr9idata.pl

Unable to execute cr9idata.pl

```
RW-50010: Error: - script has returned an error:   2
```

RW-50004: Error code received when running external process.  Check log file for details.
Running Database Install Driver for VIS instance

---

I executed command in terminal with root account:

[root@ntcs ~]# perl /u01/db/VIS/12.1.0/nls/data/old/cr9idata.pl
Directory /u01/db/VIS/12.1.0/nls/data/9idata already exist. Overwriting...
Copying files to /u01/db/VIS/12.1.0/nls/data/9idata...
Copy finished.
Please reset environment variable ORA_NLS10 to /u01/db/VIS/12.1.0/nls/data/9idata!

Thanks advanced for helping !

Comment: "Check log file for details." Without this, nobody may tell what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After serveral day debugging. I found the reason is my oracle user error.
I installed perl into /home/oracle/perl5...then make oracle user error.
I cannot su oracle from root user.
when i install perl for oracle user then .bashrc of oracle user auto add two routine line:

eval `perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib`

export MANPATH=$HOME/perl5/man:$MANPATH

I just remove above two lines above then i can su oracle from root user.

Conclusion:
When you install Oracle EBS 12.2.0 on CentOS 7.3. rapidwiz tool will su to oracle user automatically to install DB. But our oracle error cannot be su to so make error. But it show the symtom very strange so it is difficult to debug.

Now i install Oracle EBS 12.2 sucessfully !
I am very happy to share this to anyone meet this error.

Answer (score -1):

I am installing EBS 12 at the moment.

Looking a bit deeper into the logs for the cr9idata.pl script, I saw that this error is caused by a missing Perl module. The Perl version that is installed with Oracle includes this library, so setting the path manually works in that case.

If you (like me) have installed Perl from YUM, install this module: perl-File-CheckTree